# How to read PDF files using Java?

Tags: java, pdf

I want to read some text data from a PDF file using Java. How can I do that?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) is the best library I've found for this purpose, it's comprehensive and really quite easy to use if you're just doing basic text extraction. Examples can be found [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/textextraction.html).

It explains it on the page, but one thing to watch out for is that the start and end indexes when using setStartPage() and setEndPage() are **both** inclusive. I skipped over that explanation first time round and then it took me a while to realise why I was getting more than one page back with each call!

[Itext](http://itextpdf.com) is another alternative that also works with C#, though I've personally never used it. It's more low level than PDFBox, so less suited to the job if all you need is basic text extraction.

Answer (score 33):

with Apache PDFBox it goes like this:

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper; 
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;

PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));
if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String text = stripper.getText(document);
    System.out.println("Text:" + text);
}
document.close();
```

Comment: import these: `import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;`

Answer (score 19):

[PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) contains [tools for text extraction](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/textextraction.html).

[iText](http://itextpdf.com/) has more low-level support for text manipulation, but you'd have to write a considerable amount of code to get text extraction.

[iText in Action](http://www.manning.com/lowagie/) contains a good overview of the limitations of text extraction from PDF, regardless of the library used (Section 18.2: Extracting and editing text), and a convincing explanation why the library does not have text extraction support.  In short, it's relatively easy to write a code that will handle simple cases, but it's basically impossible to extract text from PDF in general.