# How to i access a specific paragraph and text from a pdf file in java

Tags: java

Can any one help me to get how can i access a specific text or paragraph from pdf file in java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to get the job done. A simple way would be to [extract the PDF as text](http://pdfbox.apache.org/userguide/text_extraction.html).

Comment: From Apache PDFBox we can access text page wise i need to access paragraph