# library to bring a pdf to code

Tags: java, pdf

I have the need to create some pdf through java code, pdf templates are fixed and are very complex too. Each pdf represents a module and I have to fill it with informations I get from other sources in my application and finally create the complete pdf.

So, is there a library which, given a pdf, scans it and creats some java code which will eventually create it back? This way once I get the pdf template in java code I just have to edit it adding my informations and create it back.

Comment: Your description of the templates is too vague. How do you have to *fill* them? Are there Acroform Form fields? Or XFA Form fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can check these 2 link it's have all information regarding PDF CRUD operation.

[How to read PDF files using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java)

http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-write-and-read-pdf-files-using-pdfone-and-java/27058

Answer (score 0):

I have used with success iText http://itextpdf.com/ for various tasks involving creating, parsing and modifying pdf files. Please not that this one is not free for commercial use and the pricing isn't cheap either.

However, your question is a possible duplicate of the folowing one, so be sure to check the answers there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java

Answer (score 0):

`itext` is one of best approach for your need..
[itext API'S](http://itextpdf.com/api)