# How to find and replace the text of pdf file in java

Tags: java, pdf

I didn't find any exact solution to find and replace the text of pdf file in java language. Please help me to short out this problem.

Comment: From [the help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."

Comment: `iText in Action` will be great reference book for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/), a nice library with some [examples](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/textextraction.html) provided.

Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java). I recommend using a google search with "site:stackoverflow" before asking question.

Comment: Link's provided are not found.

Comment: @Abhishek fixed, thanks for mentioning

Answer (score -1):

Try [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).
Read this side and search for examples and if you than has already problems, ask here a new, concret question.