# RS-Online / Farnell Java library

Tags: java, html

I am searching for an java library for getting part data from RS-Online and Farnell.
Is there anything like that out there?

In case there is not, what would be the best approach to do it on my own?
I thought about loading the website with the respective part and then search it based on html ids in order to extract the information I need.

Comment: Why are you asking us? Why aren't you asking the companies concerned?

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java
Why don't you ask adobe for an java pdf reader? Same reason...

Comment: I am not just asking for an software library, but also for an approach to do it on my own

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that using selenium server is a good approach for doing this on my own. The fetching of parts can be done in less than 200 lines of code.
Dependency to latest version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
    </dependency>
```