# searching a word in multiple pdf files and indexing pdf based on the word count

Tags: java, lucene, binary-tree

Can any one help me to search a word in multiple pdf files and to get the word count?

I need to display the pdf in descending order of word count in each document and I should do this in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for a starting point or idea rather than a specific solution - you have a few options here.

First of all you need to make sure that the text content of the PDFs is searchable. Here's [one way](http://www.ehow.com/how_5084267_make-pdf-searchable.html) for example, using Adobe Acrobat.

Secondly, you need to use some kind of API to index the PDF files so that they are searchable. Here's a [section](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_can_I_index_PDF_documents.3F) on the Apache Lucene site which may give you some hints.

> Apache Lucene is a high-performance, full-featured text search
>   engine library written entirely in Java.

Bear in mind that there isn't much context in your question so indexing the PDFs or Lucene may be overkill for you.

I recommend Googling some approaches - try "text search pdf files", "reading pdf files java", etc.

Here's an [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java) to help you out, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) for counting words in the PDF files:

```
public static int countWordInFile(String word, String filename, String fileEncoding) throws Exception {
    int count=0;
    PrintStream ps = null;
    PrintStream originalSystemOut = System.out;

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ps = new PrintStream(baos);
        System.setOut(ps);

        // Extracting text from page
        ExtractText.main(new String[] {//
                //
                        "-encoding", fileEncoding, //
                        "-console", //
                        filename //
                //
                });

        String content = baos.toString(fileEncoding);

        // TODO: Find the word in content and count its occurences...

    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(ps);
        System.setOut(originalSystemOut);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Getting data:**
Download iText (PDF tool), open all pdf's you want to scan, read the text inside of them, make a HashMap to store word -> count(word).
**Sorting your hashmap:**
this problem is already solved by stackoverflow here: [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)