# Vaadin Upload Component output stream encoding issue?

Tags: java, file-upload, encoding, vaadin, bufferedinputstream

forgive me if this has been discussed in the forum but I have been looking for answers to my problem.

I may not fully understand how the upload component is working. I plan to save a file to my server that I can later read the contents of into a table or text area.

This is my receive upload file method, where I am writing to a File and returning the FileOutputStream.

```
   public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename, String mimeType) {
            // Create upload stream
            FileOutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
            try {
                // Open the file for writing.
                outputFile = new File("/tmp/" + filename);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
                new Notification("Could not open file<br/>",
                        e.getMessage(),
                        Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE)
                .show(Page.getCurrent());
                return null;
            }
            return fos; // Return the output stream to write to
        }
```

This is my code once the upload succeeds

```
public void uploadFinished(Upload.FinishedEvent finishedEvent) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(outputFile.getAbsolutePath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        textArea.setValue(textArea.getValue() + "\n" + line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

This all works and outputs the contents of a file, eg PDF or Text file, but the contents are all wrapped with odd encoding such as

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1348\cocoasubrtf170
>   {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
>   {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
>   \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
>   \pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural
>
> \f0\fs24 \cf0 hi there\ \ bye}

where the original file held

hi there

bye

What am I doing to include all the metadata etc?

Also Id like to note I added the standardcharset.UTF8 to the input stream in hope to fix this, but it is the exact same as without including this.

Comment: It appears that you file you are reading is not a plain text file (as you mentioned PDF), to read the content of PDF or Word doc you can use some specific library to read the content.

Comment: thanks for this, Ive had a bit of an oversight here. I'll try a package like pdfbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the file is not a text file, but a PDF file. In your uploadFinished() method, you could first test the file type using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType(java.nio.file.Path). If the file is a PDF, you can use PDFBox ([How to read PDF files using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java)) to read the content, or if it is plain text, you can read it as you already are.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

...

String contentType = Files.probeContentType(outputFile.toPath());
if(contentType.equals("application/pdf"))
{
       PDDocument document = null; 
    document = PDDocument.load(outputFile);
    document.getClass();
    if( !document.isEncrypted() ){
        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
        stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
        PDFTextStripper Tstripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String st = Tstripper.getText(document);
        textArea.setValue(st);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
else if(contentType.equals("text/plain"))
{
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(outputFile.getAbsolutePath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        textArea.setValue(textArea.getValue() + "\n" + line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

}
```

Comment: thanks, ill try implementing a similar idea using package like pdfbox