# How to read the data's from pdf and insert to db?

Tags: java, mysql, pdf

I am trying to read pdf file which is containing table data and insert 
those data's into database using java.i don't know how to do this can any one help me to do this.

for example:

I am having pdf file with 3 rows ans 3 columns table with data's.
  I need to insert those column data's to table column's.

Comment: [PDF to Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read PDF files using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use iText PDF library for reading and writing.If you are using Maven project please add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```

PDF Reader will read from pdf file and pass to writer which will write to DB.
pdf reader sample example

```
public class PdfReadExample {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "/tmp/myexample.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PdfReader reader;

        try {

            reader = new PdfReader("f:/myexample.pdf");

            // pageNumber = 1
            String textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);

            System.out.println(textFromPage);

            reader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) The Apache PDFBox® library is an open source Java tool for working with PDF documents.
2. [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)

You can use these library to accomplish your task.