# How can I convert pdf to txt file with specific features?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, txt, groupdocs

For example,I have pdf like that :

1. What is a Java?
   A)Programming Language
   B)Book
   C)City

and true answer is highlighted in pdf. I need to delete (1. 2. 3.) from questions and select highlighted one for knowing true answer. Do anyone has any idea? Especially part for highlighted one

I did not try anything special yet, except converting pdf to txt in java.

Comment: There are already commercial and free tools for translating pdfs to other formats. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You could at least try to find similar questions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.
So leave a question, show us your code, what did you try and your research:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/java/converting/

Comment: Highlighted in what way? Could you upload an example PDF?