# How to decode extracted text from pdf file in android kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, pdf, inputstream, stringbuilder

I'm new to Kotlin. I am creating an application in which, after the user selects/picks a PDF file, he will see fragments of the extracted text. Unfortunately each time I read text from the PDF file it is unreadable. i.e.:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<</Title (MojPdf)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m123 Google Docs Renderer)>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</ca 1
/BM /Normal>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 326>> stream
x��SQN�0��)r�evlǉ��`l���&!����D�n*sBk�6ʋ_^�m�P��'s������~������x��arػ����5\{�H���v��Ac{+�K�c����[n*������+���J�w�d��*1e߽�??�[߽9�!BV�\�Db�䀂:���n��!�\�ϋ��R(',�)����  Z�V=P�KB.4و��Q3F�:b}9�Ιe�!wCa@�Z��4��tDV�B�??%J,�M��??P,*z.��+�����qm5e�����ej��F5��d��l9��m�@�_u�Q�v#����[�}V�(;
```

and so on...

I have already tried in various ways, adding different charsets UTF-8 and others, using reader or bufferreader...
I'm using this method to get the text from PDF:

```
val result = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
        var stringResult = remember {
            ""
        }
        var stringDienst = remember {
            ""
        }
        val applicationContext = LocalContext.current
        val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        fun readTextFromUri(uri: Uri): String {
            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
                BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")).use { reader ->
                    var line: String? = reader.readText()
                    while (line != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line)
                        line = reader.readLine()
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "stringBuilder: $stringBuilder")

            return stringBuilder.toString()
        }
        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) {
            result.value = it
            if (it != null) {
                stringResult = readTextFromUri(it)
            }
        }


        Column {
            Row {
                Button(onClick = {
                    launcher.launch(arrayOf("application/pdf"))
                }) {
                    Text(text = "Select Document")
                }
            }
            Row {
                Text(text = "stringDienst: $stringDienst")
            }
        }
```

After selecting the file and running the method, the text is completely unreadable. Thanks for any help.

Comment: PDFs are not text files, you can't read text from something that is not text. For example, neither are word documents, nor photos. You'll have to either create your own library by following the standard, or find one that is appropriate for you rneeds. For example:  [How to read PDF files using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-to-read-pdf-files-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

Pdf is not a plain-text format.

If you want to parse it, can find the specification here: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Or, preferably, you could import one of many Java/Kotlin PDF libraries and use that to read it.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your reply. I haven't solved the problem yet, but I actually didn't know that it was impossible to read PDF this way. I will be testing other libraries in the near future and I will let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes, yes, it finally happened. Thank you all very much for your help. The comments about the external library from
K J and Šimon Kocúrek led me to the appropriate solution. Here is the code using https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android
Once again, many thanks to all of you.

```
val result = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
var stringResult = remember {
    ""
}
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) {
    result.value = it
}
val applicationContext = LocalContext.current
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(applicationContext)
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun readTextFromUri(uri: Uri): String {
    contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
        PDDocument.load(inputStream).use { pdfDocument ->
            if (!pdfDocument.isEncrypted) {
                stringResult = PDFTextStripper().getText(pdfDocument)
            }
        }
    }
    return stringResult
}
```